# Css fonts are not working in IE after I disabled cache in Node JS

Tags: css, node.js, internet-explorer, caching, koa

Css fonts are not working in IE after I disabled cache in Node JS.

When the user navigates to some page and navigates back to previous page by clicking on back button, the previous page font styles are not working in IE 11.

'**koa-no-cache**' Code to disable cache

```
app.use(noCache({global: true}));
```

I used the above code to disable cache for my node application.

Any Solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the cache disabled the browser should not cache assets - including fonts. The solution would be to host the fonts from a different location where the cache is not disabled, if you want the fonts to be cached, or to disable the cache only for certain types of assets.